# How can I view a Cobertura code coverage report?

Tags: code-coverage, cobertura

I have a coverage report generated with Karma / Cobertura.

It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE coverage SYSTEM "http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/xml/coverage-04.dtd">
<coverage lines-valid="91293"  lines-covered="22464"  line-rate="0.24609999999999999"  branches-valid="50346"  branches-covered="3333"  branch-rate="0.0662"  timestamp="1478206709367" complexity="0" version="0.1">
<sources>
    <source>/home/ubuntu/my-website</source>
</sources>
<packages>
    <package name="core"  line-rate="0.4032"  branch-rate="0.2327" >
    <classes>
        <class name="ajax.js"  filename="src/ajax.js"  line-rate="0.4576"  branch-rate="0.2778" >
        <methods>
            <method name="(anonymous_1)"  hits="1"  signature="()V" >
                <lines><line number="7"  hits="1" /></lines>
            </method>
...
```

How can I use this file to view annotated code?

Comment: You have to use an editor or IDE that is compatible with Karma/Cobertura.

Comment: I have been unable to find such an editor, but I was able to get annotated code coverage by generating HTML reports instead of Cobertura reports. I think Cobertura works with Jenkins.